# Is there a way to find out which version of docker was used to build an image?

Tags: docker

I'm looking for a way to find out which version of docker was used for a given image, to determine if a specific docker engine is causing an error when building the software.

`docker image history IMAGE_ID` doesn't give me the information I require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker image inspect` command has the `DockerVersion` field which is probably what you need:

```
docker image inspect IMAGE_ID
```

Output:

```
"DockerVersion": "19.03.11"
```