# Is there any way to find the docker version used to build docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

I have docker images which have empty DockerVersion when performing docker inspect .

Is there any other way to find out the docker version used to build the docker image?

Comment: where do you want to use DockerVersion, one of  additional command is docker image history.

Comment: I want it to be available to check in future about what version of docker was used to build my image. The command docker image history does not provide this info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to find out which version of docker was used to build an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224068/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-version-of-docker-was-used-to-build-an-image)

Comment: @Pino As I mentioned for the image I am inspecting, the DockerVersion is missing.